# Why am I unable to parse formData (image upload) in NextJS with Vercel

Tags: post, next.js, fetch-api, vercel

I have some code that uploads an image and saves to s3. This works perfect locally and worked fine when deployed to a server with NGINX.

I've now switched to Vercel and it's failing.

```
export const POST = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {

console.log("Posting to image endpoint")

const middlewareResult = checkAuthHeadersAndOrigin(req);
if (middlewareResult) {
    return middlewareResult;
}

console.log("passed middleware") //here logs

const formData = await req.formData();

console.log("data", formData) //here never logs
```

From what I've read online, Vercel does not support some kind of large uploads and some advice on a stackoverlfow article was to add this:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

which I did, but now I get

```
Error: Page config in /vercel/path0/mysite/src/app/api/image/route.ts is deprecated. Replace `export const config=…` with the following:
```

But then nothing after that to tell me what to replace it with!

Here's my POST:

```
const response = await fetch(`/api/image`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'Accept': '*',
        'uid': uid,
        'email': email,
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN}`
    },
    body: imageData
});
```

Please help me determine why I can't parse formData in NextJS on Vercel.